# How do I reinstall my sound system?

Tags: 11.04, sound, indicator-sound

How can I re-install sounds, it was working very fine. I tried fix an wine sound problem. but I broke my sound on Ubuntu. indicator-sound doesn't appear

`Linux alz3abi-linux 2.6.39-0-generic-pae #5~20110427-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 27 18:53:48 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

`aplay -l` returns:

`aplay: device_list:240: no soundcards found...0`

`hz@alz3abi-linux: [ ~ ]`

`$ lspci | grep audio`

Comment: Could you update your question with output of `cat /proc/asound/pcm` and `lspci | grep -i audio`?